# Including .inc javascript file in ASP doesn't work, only .js does

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic

New to ASP and probably never named a Javascript file **".inc"** :-)
But that seems to be the norm where I'm currently working.

I observed that right on the first page I started getting these javascript errors
`Message: 'globalVariableXXX' is undefined`

I found that the javascript file wasn't getting called at all.
Just changed the name to **".js"** and it worked !!
The ASP file includes the JavaScript file like this :
`<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="include/MenuCode.inc"></SCRIPT>`

But there are 100's of these ".inc" files and 100's of references to them, hence don't want to go with this solution.
I'd rather understand it..

Any idea why it would've worked in the first place and why it isn't now ?
I'm sure I'm missing something pretty basic in ASP..

**Another point** : This application is installed on another server and it works just fine there when I hit it. I'm trying to install it on this new box.

**Where I made the change for it to work:**
In IIS, Right click on the name of the machine and the Mime Types are right over there. Checked the old server and it had the settings for ".inc", copied them and it started working :) Thanks all.

Comment: Maybe IIS is not handling *.inc as plainfiles.

Comment: If you navigate to the file directly what is the mimetype returned?

Comment: Did you change the name of the file itself AND the name in the code?  If you only changed the code, then the actual file has a .js extension and won't ever load with the .inc extension in the code...

Comment: @John - I made a copy of the file and have both a .inc & a .js version

Comment: @JamesHarris - I went to the file in explorer and the type is shown as "INC file". How do I check the mimetype ?

Comment: @PlanetUnknown, Easiest way is in firefox using firebug, goto the net tab and examine the response headers, "Content-Type" = mime type. it should be "application/javascript", or "text/javascript" or similar. The response will also tell you if it is actually returning the file at all.

Comment: @JamesHarris - There is no script returned at all !! You were right ! How do I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone changed the webserver to prevent it serving .inc files ?

Comment: This is a brand new box !! Maybe I should've mentioned that ! How do I allow it to serve them ?

Comment: In IIS (if that's what you're using) you need to add them into the MIME types section - set them to the same values as .js files. It should work OK. .inc files are not in the standard IIS 7.5 MIME types list

Comment: Do you know where I need to add this mapping ? The place where @Shadow mentioned ?

Comment: @PlanetUnknown What version IIS are you running?

Comment: this is the URL for IIS 7 Mime Type help [link]( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753281(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Worked !! In IIS, Right click on the name of the machine and the Mime Types are right over there. Checked the old server and it had the settings for ".inc", copied them and it started working :) Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

In the management console (inetmgr) right click the website and choose Properties. Go to "home directory" tab and click Configuration.

You will probably see  the `.inc` extension there (in the mapping tab) meaning those files are parsed by the ASP engine.

Remove the item from the mappings table, apply and you should be able to parse those files as raw data.

Comment: I don't see the mapping there. Also, when I checked through firebug I don't see the script returned at all !

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to use a `script` tag for javascript is with the `type` attribute, such as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/MenuCode.inc"></script>
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp
`language` isn't even listed as a supported attribute by the standard..

Edit: The reason .js worked and .inc didn't is .js is in the mime type definitions of the server as a JAVASCRIPT mime type by default. If not using an extension configured as text/javascript by default, you have to tell the browser what to treat the file as somehow. This is why the text attribute of script is a required attribute as per html 4.01.

Comment: also note the lowercase, non-screaming declaration.

Comment: The actual HTML 4 standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html And HTML 5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html

Comment: Sheridan - I doubt this is a browser specific setting issue. This app. is configured on another box and I can hit it just fine.

Comment: Please just look up how MIME types work. If the browser pulling down the inc file does not know what it is, then it won't know how to treat it. This is why we have standards.

Comment: There's no official standard says javascript files need to have .js extensions - nothing wrong with .inc if that's what you've got, the type attribute tells the browser what's supposed to be in the file.

Comment: Exactly. It's all up to either what the server is configured to serve up a file extension as (in most server configurations js defaults to text/javascript), or what you explicitly request a file extension as (type attribute)